# What is the best lint plug-in for sass files?

Tags: sass, lint, gulp-sass, stylelint

I have checked [gulp-sass-lint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-lint) and [gulp-stylelint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-stylelint), both have most wonderful rules to lint the sass file. I wonder which plugin is best to lint scss files in a node project with gulp task runner? I figured most of the stylelint rules are not supported to scss files.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to say which is "best" as each tool has its own strength and weaknesses. A lot depends on your particular use-case.

> I figured most of the stylelint rules are not supported to scss files.

This bit can be answered objectively though. All of the stylelint rules are *compatible* with SCSS syntax. Additionally, there is [`stylelint-scss`](https://github.com/kristerkari/stylelint-scss) - a plugin pack of SCSS-specific rules.